# Delphi SOAP server change output parameter name

Tags: web-services, delphi, soap, wsdl

I write standalone SOAP server using Delphi. It contains function returning version of the server, e.g.:

```
function TMySOAP.GetVersion: string; stdcall;
begin
  Result := '1.0';
end;
```

According to some specification the output value of the function should have the name 'Result', so the WSDL should look like this:

```
<message name="GetVersion3Response">
  <part name="Result" type="xs:string"/>
</message>
```

But because Delphi uses identifier 'Result' in it's own purposes, my server generates next WSDL:

```
<message name="GetVersion3Response">
  <part name="return" type="xs:string"/>
</message>
```

The name of the output parameter is hardcoded in the specification and client programs can not process answer of my server correctly because of name mismatch.

Is there any way to change the name of output parameter to 'Result'?

Answer (score 1):

Find an answer by myself:

```
procedure TMySOAP.GetVersion(out Result: string); stdcall;
begin
  Result := '1.0';
end;
```

Seems it works.

Comment: Indeed, DLLs should never pass a `String` over its boundaries - especially not as a function result.